# How to make the value of a String variable not change after once assigned?

Tags: java, android, string, final

How can I make sure that the value of String variable doesnot change after being assigned once? Assignment is not at the time of declaration.

More clarity :-

String x = y; (y is another string)
Even if y changes x should not change. How to make sure this?

What I have tried :-

Created a custom class:-

```
public class MyDs {
    private final String unitName;

    public MyDs(String iUnitName){
        unitName   =   iUnitName;

    }

    public String getUnitName(){
        return unitName;
    }
}
```

in the main method :-

```
String iName = "xyz";

MyDs MyDsObj  = new MyDs(iName);
```

But even after this, the value changes when the variable changes.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: please give more information it not very clear what you are trying to ask

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Please see the edited question.

Comment: x = y x will point to the y address.So obviously x will change when y is changed.

Comment: @Anonymous How can I do something so that x doesnot change when y changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583502/declare-final-variable-but-set-later understand this

Comment: why do you want "x = y" when x and y should be different?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran That question has no relation to the question that I asked.

Comment: @Anonymous y is assigned to x, but after that I dont want the value of x to change with changes in y.

Comment: The way you are declaring final String variable that is not possible it is a compile time error

Comment: see that answer "You can set a final variable only in a constructor or in an initializer. Regular methods cannot change the value of variables declared final", the way you making gives compile error

Comment: @Lingeshwaran I have set the value through the constructor only.

Comment: You class is correct.You are assigning value in constructor..It cannot be updated through any getter setter since the field is final.

Comment: Has this to do something with the class itself being final?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to set String value via constructor in your case?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Then how else will I do that ?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran did you try to do that? I tried I got compile time error

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat I am adding my answer with code try that

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat in Java all strings are immutable. That means their content cannot change. You think you are seeing a change, but it must be something else.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Are you sure that the meaning of the immutable is what you intended here?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Just check my solution..may be that is what you are looking for

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat yes. `String x = "abc";` means that a variable, called x, refers to a memory location in which the characters "abc" are stored and that memory location will always contain those same characters – it will not contain any other data – at least for as long as the variable x exists.

Comment: I am talking about String y = "abc";
String x =y;
If we change y = "xyz";
Will x also changed the value?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat no. Definitely not.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes what you told is correct :)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException But can I do something to make sure that y doesnot change ever after my first assigment y = "abc"?

Comment: Yes, declare it as `final`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435163/why-can-final-object-be-modified

Comment: @Anonymous SOF is not a place to post answers, ask questioner to check them and delete them if doesnot work.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat check the solution I provided.if it doesnot help you then I need to delete it

Comment: Did you check the answer tht I provided below?you can just comment there if it is not working so that I can edit and make it better

Comment: SOF is not a place to provide answers?what are you saying?then y did you post question?

Comment: @Anonymous I said you cant ask the questioner to verify the answers and then delete them :) Please understand what I posted.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat the link in your comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435163/why-can-final-object-be-modified) talks about a final variable referring to a mutable object. Strings are immutable. So final String variables cannot be changed to refer to a different object (because they're final), *and* the object they're referring cannot be changed (because it's immutable).

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your MyDs class to a singleton class

Making this a singleton class ensures that the final String `unitName` is updated only once and then it will cannot be altered again.

```
public class MyDs {
    private final String unitName;
    private static MyDs myDs;

public static MyDs getMyDsObject(String iUnitName) {
    if (myDs == null) {
        myDs = new MyDs(iUnitName);
    }
    return myDs;
}

private MyDs(String iUnitName) {
    unitName = iUnitName;

}

public String getUnitName() {
    return unitName;
}

}
```

Here the values "xyz" is stored in `unitName` and doesnot get updated again when you change to "zxy".

```
MyDs MyDsObj = MyDs.getMyDsObject("xyz");
Log.i("value", "" + MyDsObj.getUnitName());

MyDs MyDsObj1 = MyDs.getMyDsObject("zxy");
Log.i("value",""+MyDsObj.getUnitName());
```

Comment: In this context how is this different from the code that I posted in the question?

Comment: The class is singleton and the object is created only once.I have tested this in studio so I asked you whether this is what you wanted

Comment: A singleton should not have public constructors ...

Comment: @AxelH thanks for reminding that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class be should be design as mentioned in below code

public class TestingClas {

```
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    if (this.name == null && name != null)
        this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Now use below code for testing purpose

```
   TestingClas testingClas = new TestingClas();
    testingClas.setName("Abdul Waheed");
    testingClas.setName("You cannot change me any more now");

    String updatedString = testingClas.getName();
```

updatedString variable will be having old value

Comment: you havenot understood the problem.
My problem is 
String myStringVar = "xyz";
testingClas.setName(myStringVar);
Later change the value of myStringVar to 
myStringVar = "abc";

Then do testingClas.getName(), it returns "abc", instead I wanted "xyz"

Comment: try my code it will not return the abc.

Comment: How is your code in effect different from the code that I posted in the question?

Comment: I am not sending values in constructor and I am checking before setting. That is how my code differs

Comment: Do you think that will make any difference in this case?

Comment: Did you make it a try?

Comment: If you don't find you result with the code mentioned above then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand ,you should design your class in a way that your variable should be final . with this approach you set it in constructor and then nothing can make it changes. even the referance it is holding is changed the value remains the same I mean  a new object is created in heap and value of your final variable is kept same. below is a kind of design which makes the variable x set once and never be able to changed afterwards. Of course this is in instance scope, for class scope you can make your class singelton etc.

```
public class Test {

    private final String x;
    private String y;


    public Test(String x){
        this.x=x;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return x;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you question is not really clear (and the comment section is really chaty...), but if you want to only be able to set a value once but not during the initialisation, setters are not a bad choice. Just add a constraint.

```
public class MyClass{

    private static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = new String("");

    private String value = DEFAULT_VALUE;

    public final void setValue(String value){
        if(this.value != DEFAULT_VALUE) //use the reference on purpose
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This value can't be changed anymore");

        this.value = value;
    }

    // Don't return `DEFAULT_VALUE` to prevent someone to gain access to that instance
    public final String getValue(){            
        return this.value == DEFAULT_VALUE ? null : this.value;
    }
}
```

This will be done at runtime, but this would do the trick.

Now, this is an immutable instance, with some mutable instance you might want to do a copy of it to be sure it can't be modifier using the original reference.