# How to set the final variable to global variable in spring batch using context?

Tags: java, string, global

```
ItemReader<Token> tokenReader(DataSource dataSource) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    DateFormat dfFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy");
    Calendar startDateCal = Calendar.get Instance();
    startDateCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("runForNoOfDays")));
    startDateCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    startDateCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startDateCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    final String startDateStr = dateFormat.format(startDateCal.getTime());
}
```

I want to declare final `String startDateStr`  as global. Which  methods I can use?

Comment: This kind of problem is java-related. Move this code to class constructor or in a class static block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare final variable, but set later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583502/declare-final-variable-but-set-later)

Comment: See if you get something from https://stackoverflow.com/q/8117060/945214