# Should I synchronized access to a final static attribute storing a `DataSource`, that is set once at server startup?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a static final attribute storing a `DataSource`, that can be accessed by several threads. This `DataSource` is set once at Tomcat's startup.

Should I synchronized access to this `DataSource`? My concern is that maybe the internal state of the `DataSource` might be changed by one thread, and not seen by another.

It is still not clear to me if a "read-only" static field can be accessed without synchronization, or if it is mandatory in any case.

I read [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429278/1768736) that maybe only the method initializing the attribute would need to be synchronized, so my code would be OK:

```
public static final DataSource myDataSource;
static {
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    myDataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/DataSource");
}
```

But is it really OK? What is the best way of doing this performance-wise?

Comment: Since your DataSource is a '_read-only_' resource, you probably will not need to synchronize access to the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the data source reference is thread safe after if you initialize it the way you did.

Remember, that the thread-safety of methods in the data source itself is a completely different problem. Even if you properly get the object reference, it's internal state may become invalid if unsynchronized and accessed by many threads.

BTW: why not write it like that:

```
public static final DataSource myDataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("jdbc/DataSource");
```

Comment: OK thanks, makes perfect sense explained like this, my question seems completely useless to me now :p (you're right about the initialization, but I need to perform some operations in case of a NamingException, code not shown)

Answer (score 1):

java.sql.DataSource is an interface and its API does not say anything about tread safety, and so it depends on implementation. E.g. apache-dbcp BasicDataSource is thread-safe because its methods are synchronized.